# Testing a filter used within a controller function

Tags: angularjs, filter, karma-mocha

I have the following test case:

```
it('should return id if the post is successful',function(){
       var result = {
               id : "123"
       };
        ctrl.saveCallback(result);
        expect(ctrl.method.id).to.equal("123");
    });
```

Where `ctrl.saveCallback` copies the `result.id` into the `method.id` on the `ctrl` and then shows the success banner. On the success banner, we are using the `translate` filter to translate the message before showing it.

Function:

```
.....
ctrl.method.id = result.id;
magicallyShowOnScreen($filter('translate')('MESSAGES.SUCCESS'));
....
```

`magicallyShowOnScreen` is a service that shows whatever string we pass onto the screen, and that has been injected into beforeEach.

Can someone please point in the right direction as to how should I test or mock out this `$filter('translate')` ?

Comment: You using Sinon, Chai? Can you show how you're injecting `magicallyShowOnScreen` in your `beforeEach`?

Answer (score 1):

Preface: I'm not familiar with Mocha.js or how one would create spies however you would still inject them or similar mock objects the same way as you would for other testing frameworks.

Below is a Jasmine example, I hope it helps.

---

When you bootstrap your module (using the `module` / `angular.mocks.module`) function, you should provide your own version of `$filter` which should be a mock / spy that returns another mock / spy. For example

```
var $filter, filterFn;
beforeEach(module('myModule', function($provide) {
    $filter = jasmine.createSpy('$filter');
    filterFn = jasmine.createSpy('filterFn');
    $filter.and.returnValue(filterFn);

    $provide.value('$filter', $filter);
});
```

Then, in your test, you can make sure `$filter` is called with the right arguments, eg

```
expect($filter).toHaveBeenCalledWith('translate');
expect(filterFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MESSAGE.SUCCESS');
expect(magicallyShowOnScreen).toHaveBeenCalled(); // assuming this too is a spy
```